# How to find vector representing altitude of a triangle?

Tags: unity, vector, linear-algebra

I'm trying to find this green vector and I've got three points A, B, C. How can I find that vector in Unity code-wise?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the input vectors

```
   Vector3 AB =  Vector3(Bx, By, Bz) - Vector3(Ax, Ay, Az);
   Vector3 Caxis = Vector3(Cx, Cy, Cz) - Vector3(Ax, Ay, Az); // This is the vector from A to C
```

The direction of the result vector `C` we seek is the same direction as (`AB` cross `Caxis`) cross `AB`

```
   Vector3 Cdir = Vector3.Cross(Vector3.Cross(AB, Caxis), AB).Normalize();
```

Finding the magnitude is more involved.  We know that starting at the point `Cz` and going in the direction `Cdir` must intersect along `AB`

```
   Caxis - alpha * Cdir == beta * AB
```

and we need to find unknowns `alpha` and `beta`.  We can find a vector perpendicular to `Caxis`  by projecting `AB` onto the plane to which `Caxis` is normal

```
   Vector3 Cperp = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(Caxis, AB).Normalize();
```

so our equation with `alpha` and `beta` can be reduced to one unknown

```
  - alpha * (Cdir . Cperp)/(AB . Cperp) == beta
```

So solving for `alpha` (which is in fact the magnitude of our final vector `C`)

```
   Caxis == alpha * (Cdir - AB* (Cdir . Cperp)/(AB . Cperp) )
```

This is a vector equation, but we can solve for `alpha` by taking the dot product with `Caxis` on both sides.  Writing code again this is

```
   float num = Caxis.magnitude*Caxis.magnitude;
   float denom1 = Vector3.Dot(Cdir, Caxis);
   float denom2 = Vector3.Dot(AB, Caxis) * Vector3.Dot(Cdir, Cperp) / Vector3.Dot(AB, Cperp);

   float Cmag = num/(denom1 - denom2);
```

`C` is then, using the sign convention from your diagram,

```
   Vector3 C = Cmag*Cdir;
```

I'm leaving it without checks for cases where you get a divide by zero, such as when points `B` and `C` are identical.

Comment: perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can do this more simply. This vector in green is just AC with the portion parallel to AB removed.

So:

```
Vector3 AC = C - A;
Vector3 AB = B - A;

return AC - Vector3.Project(AC, AB);
```

Comment: Also, thank you for naming your points in such a way that the answer includes `AC, AB` 